# Special paste in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, paste, vba

I'm working on Excel with VBA. I need to copy and paste some information from one row to and specific destination. I'm using this code:

```
''CUSTOM MESSAGE 
Sheets("Extract").Range("AI" & sourceRow & "").Copy Destination := 
Sheets("Print").Range("H" & destRow + 7 & "")
```

The result of this code is:

[image: Actual]

But I need something like this:

[image: Needed]

As you can see, I need to change to the next row, before going out of the table. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you wrap the text in that cell? Something like this?

```
Sheets("Extract").Range("AI" & sourceRow).Copy Sheets("Print").Range("H" & destRow + 7).WrapText = True
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of the `Range()` is incorrect.

Try:

```
Sheets("Extract").Range("AI" & sourceRow).Copy Sheets("Print").Range("H" & destRow + 7)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have the same result. Like in the first image.